How to tell the difference between digital numbers and radiances
It is a rookie question but, I saw this question here trying to explain the difference between intensity values and DN. Well, based on a satellite image, how do you tell whether it has DN (raw) values or those values have been transformed into radiances?
Are the units sufficient to identify a corrected image?

is "digital number" some kind of technical term in the remote sensing community, or is this just an ad hoc description of something? please define your terms.

you might get answers in the GIS community or some other community dealing with sat images.

usually you know where the images come from, so you know what their values mean. it is quite unlikely that you analzye a satellite image you know nothing about. if the difference matters you'll know
